# How to upload the data from Excel sheet to SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to upload the data from excel to SQL table but the excel columns are not in sequence as of table column and new data should not replace the existing data in the table, it should increment the rows.

Is there any stored procedure to update the table? but the columns in excel are not in sequence.

Please suggest.

Comment: Check out the [Import and Export Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: If there is multiple table insert then you can create a `Stored procedure` and read the data from excel and pass to the stored procedure that SP will manage the insert statements

Comment: you can use `OPENROWSET` with `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` to read from excel file

Comment: Did you condifer creating a SSIS package?